Is there a way for bibtex to use \citeauthor of natbib with alpha-numeric style?
I'm using bibtex and I've always wanted to use \citeauthor while having the references described in alpha style (as we have from e.g. alpha.bst).
Is there a way to do so?
I know that using something like unsrtnat or abbrvnat would allow \citeauthor to be used, but then the references are listed by numbers.
PS. In my case, biblatex is not an option becuase I don't want to redo that when applying different journal styles.
Thanks in advance!

Welcome to TeX! Did you tried anything already? If yes, can you please provide a MWE?

The alpha citing style is, in essence, a special case of the numerical citing style, where the citation call-out isn't a number but a text string. The alpha style file doesn't store the author[s]' names when it creates the labels for the citation call-outs; hence, natbib's \citeauthor instruction  cannot recover the author name(s).

Hello. I know alpha does not provide information of authors and hence the question itself. ;)

I understand that you’ve stated biblatex is not an option for you because you don’t want to redo everything when applying to different journal styles. However, biblatex offers a compatibility mode with natbib, which I believe— though I must emphasize, I’m not entirely certain—could work in your case. If I’ve understood correctly, I think this could be achieved with a straightforward biblatex configuration.
Here is an example with comments explaining each biblatex option used, for your understanding.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber, % Use the biber backend for compiling the bibliography.
    citestyle=authoryear, % In-text citation style.
    bibstyle=numeric, % Bibliography style.
    sorting=nyt, % Order references.
    natbib=true, % Use natbib compatibility mode.
    uniquelist=false % Only show one author, e.g. (Author et al., 2023).
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\citeauthor{doe1999example} argues something important in \citeyear{doe1999example} 
\citep{doe1999example}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}

This results in the following:

Hope this helps! If not, please clarify what you're looking for, and I'll adjust accordingly to meet your needs.

Hello, and thanks so much for the answer.
This is actually what I need except that I should use bibstyle=alphabetic.
Now what I'm looking for is to achieve this with bibtex.
